# Synonimize [freelance] and [freelancing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Synonimize [freelance] and [freelancing]. They are the same thing, the [freelancing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freelancing) tag is completely superfluous and rarely used.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Done. All questions have been retagged and [freelancing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freelancing) is now a synonym of [freelance](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freelance).

Comment: Wow, Trogdor was fast today :D Thanks Cai!